# in datomic, how is it possible to find out what keys are available for reverse lookup?

Tags: clojure, datomic

The following uses a simplified datomic setup:

```
:account/user -> string
:account/email -> ref

:email/name -> string
:email/type -> keyword
```

if I have entity containing account information, it is easy to know that it has email information

```
(keys <account entity>) 
;; => [:account/user :account/email]

(:account/email <account entity>) 
;; => <email entity>
```

But on the flipside, if I look at the keys of the email entity, I do not know that it has linked account information.

```
(keys <email entity>) 
;; => [:email/name :email/type]

(:account/_email <email entity>) 
;; => <account entity>
```

how would one find out  that `:account/_email` is a valid key without trial and error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a key is valid you can use:

```
(.containsKey <email entity> :account/_email)
;; => true
```

In order to get all valid entity keys **including the reverse ones**:

```
(.touch <email entity>)
(keys (.cache <email entity>))
```

Note that `(keys)` called directly on entity returns only forward keys.

Tested on similar schema.

Side note: apart from

```
(:account/_email <email entity>)
```

you can also query to get accounts that have linked specified email:

```
(q '[:find ?a :in $ ?e :where [?a :account/email ?e] ] (db conn) (:db/id <email entity>))
```

Comment: No it definitely works on entities. Search for 'reverse' in http://docs.datomic.com/tutorial.html

Comment: You are right. I also misunderstood your question. On a positive note, I found the containsKey method on EntityMap that should do the job. Edited the answer.

Comment: brilliant! thank you. I would have definitely not figured out the `.cache` method

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query (not tested):

```
(q '[:find ?attrs
     :in $ ?e
     :where [_ ?attrs ?e]]
    my-db my-entity)
```

Comment: tested and doesn't work